# How to reorder listview items to top of listview

Tags: android, listview

I want to reorder items in a listview to the top of that listview based on a users selection, I will briefly explain what data I have and the progress i have made so far.

I have a listview that is populated by from a database (these rows change frequently in order and content)

Example 100 rows

1  Mary 34 Ireland 
2  John 12 Spain 
3  Sam  23 USA 
4. Sarah 12 Spain

When a user clicks on a row item, I can determine that position of that item clicked by that user. That's working fine.

I want to be able to save their favorite  selects from the listview and reorder their favorites to the top of the list **each time** the listview is populated from the databases.

For example if the user click on 4. Sarah, we save Sarah as a favorite and reorder Sarah to the top of the listview.

4. Sarah 12 Spain 
   ------------ 
   1  Mary 34 Ireland 
   2  John 12 Spain 
   3  Sam  23 USA

Because the listview items are changing in real-time from updates to the database im confused how to achieve this.

Any advice would be great

Comment: i found a fact that you are new to java and  android ???

Comment: Post your Adapter and Activity codes so that people can assist you better

Answer (score 0):

You can simply reorder your items by removing the item, which has to go to the top and adding the item on the top position (index = 0). The same has to be done with the actual item on the top.
Just use:

```
list.remove(item);
list.add(index, item);
```

Don't forget to call:

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Hope this helps!

---

**Edit:**
I would also recommend you, to use a new listview (with only one row) on top of your current listview, where you only add the clicked item. Then you can remove the clicked item from the bottom listview.

Comment: Thanks Edik, thats really useful, you see i have a scoreboard thats a listview, and i want to enable users to click on a person (item in an array) and store them as a favourite. Each time they refresh the listview, which will have updated items and different rows, their favorite will appear on top.

Comment: I'll need to get the id, the name of the store saved in Prefs, and check each item for a name match and then to the remove and add as you say above

Comment: Hello Jamie, glad to hear i could help.

Comment: If you get your app working with this solution, i would be happy if you could accept my answer, so anybody with the same problem might get helped. Thank you Jamie!